# Using between in a case statement not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query to generate a report, using between to check if a date is in a range.

For some reason this is not working, even though when I output the data I know it is correct.

Any ideas why its not working?

Here is my SQL

```
SELECT @ReportDate 
SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1, @ReportDate), DATEADD(dd, -30, @ReportDate)

SELECT  i.Total, i.DateDue, c.Email, 
    CASE 
    WHEN i.DateDue BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -1, @ReportDate) AND DATEADD(dd, -30, @ReportDate) THEN '1 - 30'
    WHEN i.DateDue BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -31, @ReportDate) AND DATEADD(dd, -60, @ReportDate) THEN '31 - 60'
    WHEN i.DateDue BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -61, @ReportDate) AND DATEADD(dd, -90, @ReportDate) THEN '61 - 90'
    WHEN i.DateDue BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -91, @ReportDate) AND DATEADD(dd, -120, @ReportDate) THEN '91 - 120'
    ELSE '> 120' END
    AS [Group]
FROM    Data i
```

And the data results:

```
ReportDate
2014-07-03 11:46:02.467

First Range
Start                   End
2014-07-02 11:46:02.467 2014-06-03 11:46:02.467

Total   DateDue                 Email                   Range
121535  2014-06-17 08:50:05.440 customer3@example.com   > 120
833208  2014-06-26 08:50:19.613 customer3@example.com   > 120
381400  2014-06-18 08:50:20.177 exmployee1@example.com  > 120
```

Comment: Create a fiddle replicating the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ranges are inverted - the date on the left of `BETWEEN` is always *after* the date on the right. Switch the sides to make your query work as expected:

```
SELECT  i.Total, i.DateDue, c.Email, 
    CASE 
    WHEN i.DateDue BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -30, @ReportDate) AND DATEADD(dd, -1, @ReportDate) THEN '1 - 30'
    WHEN i.DateDue BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -60, @ReportDate) AND DATEADD(dd, -31, @ReportDate) THEN '31 - 60'
    WHEN i.DateDue BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -90, @ReportDate) AND DATEADD(dd, -61, @ReportDate) THEN '61 - 90'
    WHEN i.DateDue BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -120, @ReportDate) AND DATEADD(dd, -91, @ReportDate) THEN '91 - 120'
    ELSE '> 120' END
    AS [Group]
FROM    Data i
```